# How to create a table column from a vector of data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, r, vector

New to SQL here.
I have experience using R to create tables/data frames from vectors of data. Here is an example of some basic R code that accomplishes what I'm trying to do in MySQL.

```
df = data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3), var2 = c('a','b','c'))
```

produces

```
     var1 var2
1    1    a
2    2    b
3    3    c
```

I want to know how to do this in MySQL.

For example, I could write:

```
create table dummytable select 1 as var1, a as var2;
```

And I'd get a one-row table with 1 in column 1 and b in column 2.
But how would I replace 1 and a above with vectors of data, so that the table I'm creating has multiple rows?

Clearly this won't work, but what I'm looking for is something like:

```
create table dummytable select c(1,2,3) as var1, c('a','b','c') as var2;
```

What basic function am I missing to create and use vectors?

Comment: In SQL it might be `insert into dummy (var,var2) values (1,'a'),(2,'b'),....` From R, it might be as easy as `DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "dummy", mydataframe)`, or other functions such as `DBI::dbCreateTable` or `DBI::dbAppendTable`.

Comment: The problem with the insert method is that I'd have to create row-wise entries e.g., (1,a) and (2,b) rather than column-wise entries (1,2) and (a,b), which would make the rapid construction of a table quite difficult, with data type changing much more often between entries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MySQL handy, but this is tested in SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and SQLite.

```r
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
DBI::dbExecute(conn, "create table dummytable (var1 int, var2 nchar(3))")
# [1] 0
DBI::dbExecute(conn, "insert into dummytable (var1, var2) values (1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3,'c')")
# [1] 3
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from dummytable")
#   var1 var2
# 1    1    a
# 2    2    b
# 3    3    c
mydat <- data.frame(var1 = 4:5, var2 = c("d", "e"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn, "dummytable", mydat, append = TRUE)
DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from dummytable")
#   var1 var2
# 1    1    a
# 2    2    b
# 3    3    c
# 4    4    d
# 5    5    e

# equivalent to dbWriteTable:
DBI::dbAppendTable(conn, "dummytable", mydat)
```

Comment: My worry is about this line: (1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3,'c'), as it means there can't be a simple 1:100 call to quickly fill out 100 rows down a column. I wonder if this is simply a strength of R / a weakness of SQL.

Comment: There is not a simple line in SQL to insert (say) `var1=[1,2,...,100],var2=['a','b',...,'cv']`, and I have not seen/heard of any mention of adding it to ANSI SQL or any specific dialect (though I am not an SQL expert). Since you tagged with the [tag:r], is there a problem using the above syntax and/or "binding parameters" with `DBI::dbBind`? (ref: https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/)

Comment: I have never used DBI but I will look into it, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that since you tagged it as [tag:r] and included some R code that you were intending to implement something in R. Lacking that, then the answer to your question of doing this solely in SQL is "probably not". That type of question might also be appropriate at [dba.se].